# Undefined name 'ConflictAlgorithm'

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I'm having an error while executing the insert query

```
final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
    final db = await sql.openDatabase(path.join(dbPath, 'history.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE history(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, senderEmail TEXT, receiverEmail TEXT, amount REAL)');
    }, version: 1);

await db.insert(table, data, conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
```

The errors occurred when I passed ConflictAlgorithm.replace, says that

> Undefined name 'ConflictAlgorithm'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Also, I am following:

- https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite
- https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/conflict_algorithm.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are importing `sqflite` with a prefix (`sql`) so instead of

```dart
ConflictAlgorithm.replace
```

you should use:

```dart
sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace
```